# One word for 'something that can be overlooked'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for something that can be overlooked.  Does a word like 'overlookable' exist?

Google throws up only Urban Dictionary or Wiktionary suggestions which I suppose are not standard English grammar websites. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide more context, please? Try to include an example phrase that will make it easier to narrow down the answers. As it is, "trivial", "insignificant" or "inconsequential" come to mind.

Comment: My answer below assumes that by "overlook" you are talking about something easily missed, rather than something from which you can see (e.g.) the ocean.

Comment: Hi, agomonee, you need to edit your post with full context and an example sentence. Is it so **trivial**, **unimportant**, **insignificant** and **trifling** that they could be overlooked or ignored? The following is the strict rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or 

phrase must include information on how it will be used in order 

to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase 

request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Do you mean “it would be easy to overlook it”, or “overlooking it would not cause problems”?  These are two very different things that your wording could indicate.

Comment: There could be some **subtle** nuances to this question that make it hard to suggest the best word(s).

Comment: I came here to ask what @PLL asked.  IMO, this question is not answerable until PLL's question is answered.

Comment: Apparently can't post an answer.. *innocuous* in the 'unexceptionable' sense.

Comment: How about `arcane`?

Answer (score 25):

*Inconspicuous* things are easily overlooked.

> **Inconspicuous** 
>   Not clearly visible or attracting attention
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inconspicuous)

Answer (score 9):

***[Negligible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negligible)*** conveys the meaning you are referring to:

> - of little consequence as to warrant little or no attention :  trifling *a negligible error*
>     (M-W)

Comment: Although not a native English speaker, I think "negligible" does not match here. As your quote already says, it refers to something that does no harm to be neglected. I take the OP as for something that can easily happen to be overlooket, however this could potentially harm a lot.

Comment: @chiccodoro - OP does not say anything about  the 'potencial harm' you are referring to. It is just your own personal view.

Comment: this was not the point I was trying to make. But since the question was not clear enough and got closed meanwhile I reckon it is not worth to discuss it further.

Answer (score 7):

Inconsequential: adj.   Lacking importance.

Answer (score 4):

**[obscure](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/obscure_1)**

> not known about, or not well known

[also](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscure)

> 4. Not readily noticed or seen; inconspicuous

Comment: As a programmer, this makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

This question needs more specifics to answer properly.

*Overlook* has several senses. In the sense of 'look over' ("this room overlooks the ocean') you could use 'dramatic' or 'scenic' to say it is worth overlooking. In the sense of 'choose not to see' ("we will overlook your persistent lateness") you could use 'unimportant' or 'trivial'. In the sense of 'failing to notice'("he overlooked one important fact") you could use 'missable'.

Answer (score 3):

Omissible, perhaps?

adjective
1. capable of being or allowed to be omitted

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the intended meaning of "overlook", ***subtle*** may be worth considering.

Standard reminder that the way we used to answer best-word questions was to bounce back and forth between a thesaurus and a dictionary, and the web has made that even easier. Checking the first entry to come to hand suggests:  *attenuated, ethereal, exquisite, faint, fine, finespun, hairline, hairsplitting, illusive, implied, inconspicuous, indirect, indistinct, inferred, slight, suggestied, tenuous, thin, understated* (plus a few others farther from the intended meaning).

Answer (score 1):

Omit, (omissible) springs to mind but that may not be the sense of the word that you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'Irrelevant'? It fits the definition but it can come off a bit more dismissive than some of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Picayune. It means "of little value or significance".

Answer (score -2):

I think "scan" would be enough.

Comment: I don't see how 'scan' is appropriate to the question.  Could you please explain.

Comment: I scan through your email or I overlook your email sounds similar

Comment: Overlook doesn't mean overview. Overlook means miss, fail to notice.

Comment: Overview has a different meaning and not related to scan. Overlook is an action done carelessly